# What happened with T12's tiger children in Sherni movie?

Tags: plot-explanation, sherni

Movie [Sherni](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt10741542/) (2021), The story of a female character **Vidya** saving female tiger T12 and her 2 children from bad peoples.

Unfortunately, T12 tiger killed by bad peoples and 2 innocent children hides somewhere, Vidya trying to investigate the murder and trying to find and save T12's children but she can't, Vidya lose hope, but after a day she got a phone call from helpful people from the jungle and she got T12's both children after that she takes relief and deep breath,

The next minute the scene moved to an animal museum, there Vidya and 2 persons are managing things in the museum, but there is no update about T12's 2 children, is she able to save cubs from bad peoples, where the children moved or rescued by any forest department?